# Playstore : Deactivation of this APK will result in your app being available for new installs on fewer types of devices

Tags: android, androidx, google-play-console, android-build, android-10.0

Playstore is showing this warning when I try to upload the builds to release.
I havent changed the min and max SDK version of the app.

```
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 23
    versionName "1.04"
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Adding a new required hardware feature, removing 32-bit support, removing support for certain screen sizes, etc. Only you know what you have changed.

Comment: @Michael I dont remember adding or removing anything you mentioned. But is there any possibility that now that Android 11 is released and my SDK tagets to 29 only. Is it creating the problem?